# Using MySQL CASE to update 1000s of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table keeping track of usage by customers, a simplified structure having the columns `id` and `voice_activity`. `id` is the index and `voice_activity` expects a date as `MM-DD-YYYY` which indicates when usage was last shown.

I need to process large log files (CSV up to 200k lines) which is working fine, the issue is efficiently updating the `activity` field. It currently works by just building a single query like:

```
UPDATE users SET voice_activity = '09-24-2013' WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3
```

etc etc. This works fine, provided the log files are added in chronological order. If a log file from a previous day is added after a more recent one, the SQL query overwrites a more recent date. So the query needs to factor in whether the field `voice_activity` is greater than the date we're looking to insert, and if so not to bother.

I understand this should be possible via `CASE` but can't get my head around the syntax. If it's not possible this way, what other efficient way is there to update this table? I don't want an SQL update in a loop as that will melt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly you could use the following:
This will update the `voice_activity` column only when the new date is greater than current value..

Also note use of [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) to avoid too many ORs

```
UPDATE users SET voice_activity = '09-24-2013' WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3) and voice_activity<'09-24-2013'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE users SET voice_activity = '09-24-2013' WHERE id in(1,2,3) and voice_activity >'09-24-2013'
```

or

```
UPDATE users SET voice_activity = '09-24-2013' WHERE (id=1 or id=2 or id=3)  and voice_activity >'09-24-2013'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you really want to use CASE, although there's no need for it:

```
UPDATE users SET voice_activity = (CASE WHEN voice_activity < '09-24-2013' THEN '09-24-2013' ELSE voice_activity END) WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3
```